Upload a file in strapi and connect it to an Entry. (React Native and Strapi)
I'm using react native and I'm trying to upload an image to strapi and connect it an Entry. As the user completes there profile, I also want them to upload there profile picture. But when I upload the picture, It uploads to my server storage but it doesn't connect to the user entry that I want.
What am I not doing right?
async function uploadImage(imgUri: string, jwt: string, refId: string, ref: string, source: string, field: string) {
  try {
    const uploading = await
      FileSystem.uploadAsync(
        `https://myurl.cloud/api/upload/?refId=${refId}&ref=${ref}&source=${source}&field=${field}`,
        `${imgUri}`,
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwt}`
          },
          uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
          fieldName: "files",
        });
    return uploading
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null,2))
    return null
  }
}


I recommand you to use a custom Strapi route/controller to do this.
You can send the picture across a custom route in multipart data:
// Front-end - Send the Profile Picture to the backend
const addProfileInfo = async ({ profilePictureUri }) => {

    let data = new FormData();

    const url = 'https://myurl.cloud';

    data.append('profilePicture', {
        uri: profilePictureUri, // The only thing you need is the picture URI. Depends on what you are using to pickup the picture, the uri is the local link to it
        name: 'user-pp.jpeg', // You can name it as you want, it is not very important
        type: 'image/jpeg', // This setting 'image/jpeg' works also for png files
    });

    // Do request
    const response = await fetch(url + '/api/profile', { // Assuming you will create a route for `/api/profile` for example
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, // Don't forget to add the user JWT token
        },
        body: data,
    });

    const body = await response.json();

    return [response, body];
}


In the controller, you can now use the upload service to save your image.
// Backend - Strapi Controller for POST '/api/profile' route

// Here you recover the picture sent in the request under the name 'profilePicture'
const picture = ctx.request.files.profilePicture;

if (!picture) {
    return ctx.badRequest('Profile picture needed');
}

await strapi.plugin("upload").services.upload.upload({
        data: {
            ref: 'plugin::users-permissions.user',
            refId: ctx.state.user.id,
            field: 'profilePicture', // Here is the image field name created in Strapi to link the image to.
            source: 'users-permissions',
            fileInfo: {
                caption: undefined,
                alternativeText: undefined,
                name: 'profilePictureImg',
                folder: 1, // Folder ID 1 is the root Media library folder, but you can customize where the file can be stored in the Strapi media library by giving its id. Notice that it is a virtual folder, Strapi Media library only
            },
        },
        files: {
            path: picture.path,
            name: picture.name,
            type: picture.type,
            size: picture.size,
        },
    });

As I said, you can customize the folder where the file will be located on Strapi's Media Library, but it is another topic so I didn't developed it.
You can also send more data through this route to register more user information, but it is also another topic. Refer to Send multipart data form Strapi for further information.
Hope this help !
